# Multiple initialisation with given input parameter

Tags: python, oop

I am trying to make my class to be executed a given number of times according to passed parameter. My class converts dictionary into some desired data.

Let me show You a quick example of what i mean exactly:

First class `A` just offers common methods for derivative classes.

```
class A(object):
    @staticmethod
    def do_magic(obj):
    # ...
    print(''.obj)
```

Class `B`, `E` (skipped in example) initialise objects and provide `b_stuff` and `e_stuff`.

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self, mydict):
    #
    self.b_stuff = [...]
```

Now Class `C` comes into play. It basically transforms given dictionary `mydict` which has a key-value pair describing number of iterations `'iters': 'val'`

```
class C(B, E):
    def __init__(self, mydict):
        B.__init__(self, mydict) # access to b_stuff
        E.__init__(self, mydict) # access to e_stuff

        self.iters = int(self.mydict['iters'])     # desired nb of initialisations/executions
        self.c_stuff = [b_stuff, e_stuff, other]        

    def do_magic(self):
        A.do_magic(self.c_stuff)
```

Now the problem is, that once calling a class from external loop later in code i don't know how to make my class to `do_magic` `mydict['iters']` number of times.

```
for d in list_of_dicts:
    C(d).do_magic()
```

One of solutions could be that i'll initialise this class just in external loop above, like that:

```
for d in list_of_dicts:
    for i in range(int(d['iters']))
        C(d).do_magic()
```

But it feels far away from OOP style.

To be 100% sure that You folks follow me, ill show here actual expected behaviour:

`d` - input dictionary
`d['iters'] = 2`

**Execute**

```
C(d).do_magic()
```

**Actual result:**

```
>>> 
'XXX YYY RANDOM_NUMBER1 .... '
```

**Expected result:**

```
>>> 
'XXX YYY RANDOM_NUMBER1 .... '  
'XXX YYY RANDOM_NUMBER2 .... '  # random number from class B re-initialised!!
```

As exploring stack i've found out some hints to refer `__new__` method but still no clue if this is a right path and how :)

**Edit**:

As @Peter-wood suggested - adding to a question:

I'd like to point out that both attributes `b_stuff` and `e_stuff` once initialised - produce **unique strings** that are part of `c_stuff` and are about to be updated with each `do_magic()` call.

This method basically does `''.join(obj)` (see class A)

Answer (score 1):

```
class C(B, E):
    def do_magic(self):
        for _ in range(self.iters):
            A.do_magic(self.c_stuff)
```

Comment: This is nice but didn't work exactly as I expected because: In `b_stuff` i have some `random_number` that is generated within each initialisation and needs to be unique, solution that You provided refers to the same originally initialised value. But thanks anyway.

Comment: @TestuserSemathopy Put that in the question.